# Pandas column lost after getting mean value of time duration

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df ,you can have it by copy and run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """
 b_id          duration1                  duration2                          user  cases
 
 366           NaN                        38 days 22:05:06.807430            Test  4
 367           0 days 00:00:05.285239     NaN                                Test  4
 368           NaN                        NaN                                Test  4
 366           NaN                        38 days 22:05:06.807430            Test  4
 
 466           NaN                        38 days 22:05:06.807430            Tom   3
 467           0 days 00:00:05.285239     NaN                                Tom   3
 467           0 days 00:00:05.285239     NaN                                Tom   3


"""
df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df
```

Then I use the following code to get the mean value of duration1 and duration2 :

```
out = (df
   .set_index('user')
   .filter(like='duration')
   .apply(pd.to_timedelta)
   .groupby(level=0).mean()
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
    user    duration1   duration2
0   Test    0 days 00:00:05.285239  38 days 22:05:06.807430
1   Tom 0 days 00:00:05.285239  38 days 22:05:06.807430
```

My question is how to keep the column 'cases' in the output.The correct output should looks like:

```
    user    duration1   duration2                               cases
0   Test    0 days 00:00:05.285239  38 days 22:05:06.807430     4
1   Tom 0 days 00:00:05.285239  38 days 22:05:06.807430         3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward in my opinion is to use both columns as index/grouper. This way you still benefit from the easy conversion to timedelta.

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['user', 'cases'])
   .filter(like='duration')
   .apply(pd.to_timedelta)
   .groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   user  cases              duration1               duration2
0  Test      4 0 days 00:00:05.285239 38 days 22:05:06.807430
1   Tom      3 0 days 00:00:05.285239 38 days 22:05:06.807430
```

Comment: what if I need add one more string column ,can I do ,out = (df
   .set_index(['user', 'cases','type'])
   .filter(like='duration')
   .apply(pd.to_timedelta)
   .groupby(level=[0,2]).mean()
   .reset_index()
 ) ,I tried ,it not work

Comment: it should be `[0, 1, 2]`, or `['user', 'cases','type']`